# JobIntentService get destroyed , When app is destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin

As From android developer [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) When running on Android O or later, the work will be dispatched as a job via **`JobScheduler.enqueue`**. When running on older versions of the platform, it will use **`Context.startService`**.

In my case i am learning **`JobIntentService`** and in my case i have a timer that run every one second and display the current date and time but when my app get destroyed the **`JobIntentService`** also get destroyed, How can i run it when app is destroyed

**JobIntentService**

```
class OreoService : JobIntentService() {

    private val handler = Handler()

    companion object {
        private const val JOB_ID = 123

        fun enqueueWork(cxt: Context, intent: Intent){
            enqueueWork(cxt,OreoService::class.java,JOB_ID,intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {

        toast(intent.getStringExtra("val"))

        Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                println(Date().toString())
            }

        }, Date(),1000)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        toast("Service Destroyed")
    }

   private fun toast(msg: String){

       handler.post({
           Toast.makeText(applicationContext,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       })
   }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application
....... >
<service android:name=".service.OreoService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
</application>
```

**MainActivity (When button is pressed the service get started)**

```
startServiceBtn.setOnClickListener({
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra("val","testing service")
            OreoService.enqueueWork(this,intent)
        })
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> i am learning JobIntentService and in my case i have a timer that run every one second and display the current date and time

That is not a suitable use for `JobIntentService` (or pretty much anything else, for that matter).

> when my app get destroyed the JobIntentService also get destroyed

The point of `JobIntentService` is to do a little bit of work — some disk I/O, some network I/O, etc. — and then go away. It is *not* for doing something indefinitely, and it is *not* suitable for starting asynchronous work, and you are trying to do both. Once `onHandleWork()` ends, the service goes away, and your process can be terminated at any point in time after that, which will stop your `Timer`.

> How can i run it when app is destroyed

You are welcome to use a foreground `Service`, not an `IntentService` or `JobIntentService`. Return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` to ask Android to restart your service if your process is terminated (e.g., due to low memory conditions). Even that may be terminated by the user, but it is the user's device, not yours, and so the user can do whatever the user wants.

Comment: What will happen to `JobIntentService` if the Activity is Destroyed after starting of the `JobIntentservice` but the app is not cleared from the recent screen will the `JobIntentService` continue or will it also Stop? Also can the user block(from the settings) `JobIntentService` from running.

Comment: @RajeshK: "will the JobIntentService continue or will it also Stop?" -- it is decoupled from the activity, so it should continue to run. "Also can the user block(from the settings) JobIntentService from running" -- there is no way for the user to prevent you from starting it. The user can stop it (e.g., via Force Stop in Settings).

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer.

Comment: i am print 1 to 1000 in background working fine when its on recents apps but not working when the app destroy using jobintentservice anybody knows why its happening it must be run in background

Answer (score -2):

> On `WAKE_LOCK` How android system will know to run your `Intent service`? There should be some receiver which should receive some `intent-action`, upon which, it can run your receiver code, upon which from your receiver code you can call or start your service or intent service..!!

---

Here is sample Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".WatchMan"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
  </service>
</application>
```

Above manifest first asks permission `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Then tells that when `BOOT_COMPLETED` start my receiver `MyReceiver`.

---

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("BootTest : ", "\nOnBootReceiver - Received a broadcast!");
        Toast.makeText(context, "OnBootReceiver Received a broadcast!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
        }
        else
        {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Which in turns starts `WatchMan Service`... Hope it helps..

Comment: The code is to receive another intent action, you have to change it as per your intent action